# Application getting crash on overriding layoutSubviews method in custom view iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I am creating a customize view and need to update its subview frame on orientation change. To accomplish this I am overriding layoutSubviews in parent view.

In layoutSubviews, I am removing previous constraint and adding new constraints to its subview.

I am calling `[super layoutSubviews];` first in overriden method. It is working fine in iOS8 onwards but getting crash on iOS 7.0 and below iOS8.
Getting following message in log

`Terminated due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' reason Auto layout still required after executing layoutSubviews. Parent view's layoutSubviews needs to call super.`

If I call `[super layoutSubviews];` after modifying the constraints i.e at last in layoutSubviews, it's working in iOS7 and iOS8 both.

My question is what is the correct way to override layoutSubviews.

Am I doing something wrong?

Should we add constraint on subview in layoutSubviews.
or Is there any more better approach to achieve the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I call [super layoutSubviews]; after modifying the constraints... it's working in iOS7 and iOS8 both.

That is the correct approach - you should modify constraints *before* you call `[super layoutSubviews];`. That way AutoLayout takes into account your updated constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it wrong I think. As it says in error, it needs auto-layout constraints when it tries to layout it's subviews. So before you call `[super layoutSubviews]` you should handle constraint stuff.

Comment: Thanks Candost for your comment.